# What are the recommended approaches for an event system in Java?

Tags: java, architecture, rpg

What are the recommended approaches for an event system of a turn-based RPG's battle engine?

The system I'm currently working on has a `runEvent` method that sorts the actions queue based on their priorities. This method should also call the object's (item, player, condition) method according to an `eventid`, which currently is a `String` ("TurnStart", "TurnEnd", etc). The different objects may or may not have the same parameters for the same `eventid`.

In JavaScript, it would be something like the following:

```
retval = action['on' + eventid].apply(this, args);
```

I've read about using Java's Reflection to call a method through a `String` stored in a variable, but some people advise against it because of its security flaws.

I also thought about having a `switch (eventid)` inside a handler method that would call the appropriate method, but I think that would become impractical, given the substantial amount of different parameters combinations.

So, what is the recommended approach for this kind of situation in Java?

Note: It doesn't need to be based on `String` passing.

Comment: No 100% inline with your question, but if you're already comfortable with JavaScript you could look into offloading your event logic there using the [Rhino JavaScript Engine built into Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure if I understand the question correctly so forgive me if my answer if off, but this is how I would go about a turn-based event system.

Firstly, the actions that are represented by strings and ids can be converted into something more object-oriented which would be something like:

```
public abstract class Action {
    public abstract void execute();
}
```

That way you don't have to use switch or if-else statements; you would have to extend the action class.

To sort these actions out I would probably use an enumeration as each instance implements `Comparable`:

```
public enum Priority {
    PRE_TURN, PHASE, POST_TURN
}
```

And implement it into the action class like so:

```
private Priority priority;

public Action(Priority priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public Priority getPriority() {
    return priority;
}
```

`Action` is an abstract class because there are no arguments in the `execute` method. This means you will have to specify the necessary fields in the constructor of the extending class which acts as a work-around to the many different parameters. It also enforces you to specify its priority. An example would be:

```
public class BattlePhase extends Action {
    private Entity e, Entity target;
    private Attack attack;

    public BattlePhase(Entity e) {
        this(e, e.inLineTarget(), e.getCurrentAttack());
    }

    public BattlePhase(Entity e, Entity target, Attack attack) {
         super(Priority.MEDIUM);
         this.e = e;
         this.target = target;
         this.attack = attack;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        attack.perform(e, target);
    }
}

Character c = scene.currentCharacter();
scene.queueAction(new BattleAction(c, selectedTarget, c.getMove(selectedMove)));
```

In the class that manages event you could use a [priority queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) that will sort actions added to the queue if you specify a 'Comparator'.

```
Queue<Action> actions = new PriorityQueue<>(10, new Comparator<Action>() {
    public int compare(Action a1, Action a2) {
        return a1.getPriority().compareTo(a2.getPriority());
    }
});
```

(the first argument, 10, is the initial capacity)

Or you could use a `List` and sort it when you add actions by calling the `Collection#sort`

Then your `runEvent` method would be something like:

```
public void runEvent() {
    Action a;
    if ((a = actions.poll) != null) {
        a.execute();
    }
}
```

That's just the outline of it, you might want to add a procedure to sequence the actions so that they don't all run at once.

Answer (score 0):

ouch ! ... eventing is normally pub sub ... I say "this happened" and you as a handler go "ok now i need to do ..." this presumably is like some sort of action list system in which case I would implement it as such.

Does java have lambdas yet?
I would have somehting like this in c# ...

```
class EventManager 
{
    List<Action> actions;

    void AddAction(Action action)
    {
        actions.Add(action);
        actions.Sort(...);
    }

    void ExecuteNextAction()
        var nextAction = actions.FirstOrDefault();
        if(nextAction != null)
           nextAction();
    }
}
```

then you can do something like ...

```
var actionManager = GetTheGlobalactionManagerFromSomewhere();

actionManager.AddAction(() => 
{ 
   DoStuff(); 
   DoMoreStuff();
});
```

You could also make ActionManager static if its a global thing.
This is sort of how tasks work in .Net but with added clever threading abstraction.